# crreating function to display image from database stored path

Tags: php, database, image

I am creating a recipe book (just to keep practising working with databases), and again, I am stuck...

I have been able to display the image, but in a bad way (I think)...
What I have done so far:

In my index.php:

```
$recipes = get_recipes();
$attachments = get_attachments();
$attachments_paths = get_image_path();

echo '<h2>recipes</h2>';
echo '<table id="recipesTable" border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Recipe ID</th>';
echo '<th>Recipe Name</th>';
echo '<th>Attachment ID</th>';
echo '<th>Attachment path</th>';
echo '<th>Attachment image</th>';
echo '</tr>';
foreach ($recipes as $recipe) {   
  echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $recipe['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $recipe['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $recipe['attachment_id'] . '</td>';
    foreach ($attachments_paths as $attachment_path) {
        if ($recipe['attachment_id'] === $attachment_path['id']) {
            echo '<td>' . $attachment_path['attachment_path'] . '</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '<td>' . echo display_image(); . '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

functions.php:

```
 function get_recipes() {
    include'db_connection.php';
    try {
        return $conn->query("SELECT * FROM recipes");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error:' . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
        return array();
    }
    return true;
}

function get_attachments() {
    include'db_connection.php';
    try {
        return $conn->query("SELECT * FROM attachments");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error:' . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
        return array();
    }
    return true;
}

function get_image_path() {
    include 'db_connection.php';

    $sql = 'SELECT recipes.name, attachments.id, attachments.attachment_path FROM attachments LEFT JOIN recipes ON recipes.attachment_id=attachments.id';

    try {
        $results = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $results->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
        return array();
    }
    return $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function display_image() {
     foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
         $file = $attachment['attachment_path'];   
         return '<img src="' . $file . '" />';
 }
```

}
Columns for "recipes" table:
id, name, created, duration, source, categories_id, attachment_id, chef_id

Columns for "attachments" table:
id, attachment_path, recipe_id

And also mention, that I saved the path to the images as:
http://localhost/cooking_book/images/mistique.jpeg

If there is a better way to do this please, let me know!

So, as you can see, my display_image() is not working at all, I know the foreach loop is doing nothing there....I just don't have anything else in mind I can do, any suggestions will be appreciated :)

Comment: How does the HTML source not meet your expectations?

Comment: You should not store full URLs, that makes your setup very inflexible. What if the domain changes for example? Or the base layout, so that it is not `/images/` any more?

Comment: I know! more or less I know......I read it yesterday, and I tried so many times to do it with dirname(__FILE__), but I got frustrated after a while.... Should I get the realtive path with dirname(__FILE__) right?

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez, I guess it is a polite way of saying my html is bad... right? I know it could be better, but where I struggle is when I have to retrieve and store data on the database, so I am not worrying about the html at the moment; I guess, if I "finish" this project, I will improve the html, but at the moment I just want to understand databases

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am sure it is not the best approach, I will work on it, but at least, I am displaying the image now;

The function can't be more basic....

```
function get_image_path() {
    include 'db_connection.php'; 

      $sql = 'SELECT recipes.name, attachments.id, attachments.attachment_path FROM attachments LEFT JOIN recipes ON recipes.attachment_id=attachments.id'; 

     try {
      $results = $conn->prepare($sql);   
      $results->execute();
     } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
        return array();
    }
      return $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
}

function display_image() {
     include 'db_connection.php'; 

       return $image_path = get_image_path();       
}
```

To display it, on index.php, I just added another field to my table:

```
echo '<td>';
    foreach ($images as $img) {
        echo '<img class="attachment" src="' . $img['attachment_path'] . '"/>';
  } 
 echo '</td>';
```

Still, if anyone has a suggestion for a better option, let me know please :)